# Java Game freezes at fighting

Tags: java, swing, paint, freeze, paintcomponent

i'm just programming a java game and what i want to do is that when i press space, the character goes into fight mode for 5 sec and then release it. i already have done, that i press one time, fight mode gets enabled and when i press another time, its getting released but when i try it like this (code at bottom) the game just freezes for 5 sec but nothing happens and i don't even get a error code.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Zeichnen extends JPanel {

    int x = 10;
    int y = 335;
    int width = 100;
    int height = 106;
    int speed = 10;
    boolean left = false;
    boolean fight = false;
    String file = "res/character.png";
    Image character;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        character = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file);
        g.drawImage(character, x, y, width, height, this);
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        if (left == false) {
            left = true;
            if (fight == true) {
                x = x + 129;
                width = -129;
            } else if (fight == false) {
                x = x + 100;
                width = -100;
            }
        }
        x = x - speed;
        rand();
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        if (left == true) {
            left = false;
            if (fight == true) {
                x = x - 129;
                width = 129;
            } else if (fight == false) {
                x = x - 100;
                width = 100;
            }
        }
        x = x + speed;
        rand();
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        y = y - speed;
        repaint();
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        y = y + speed;
        repaint();
    }

    public void fight() {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fight = true;
        file = "res/character_fight.png";
        if (left == true) {
            width = -129;
        } else if (left == false) {
            width = 129;
        }
        repaint();
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > curTime + 5000) {
            fight = false;
            file = "res/character.png";
            if (left == true) {
                width = -100;
            } else if (left == false) {
                width = 100;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void rand() {
        if (x <= -130) {
            x = 770;
        } else if (x >= 770) {
            x = -130;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to work more on pinpointing your problem, you will not likely get any answers unless you can find more specific details about what is wrong. Use a debugger and step through it.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), this was reason for down_voting by some of users ...

Answer (score 1):

The `paint` chain mechanism should be observed, you should override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`. Also don't load images when painting, load them when the `JPanel` is being initialised.

Comment: I think getImage caches the request for that filename. However, it is best to load the needed images once.  

--

Definitely override paintComponent instead of paint (especially since you're correctly making the superclass call to paintComponent). You don't want to accidentally get yourself into a recursive-call loop if super.paintComponent calls paint. From the paint doc: "This method actually delegates the work of painting to three protected methods: paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren."

--

Also, places you have tests like "if(left == true)", you can make that just "if(left)" :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your problem, you want that at the pression of a key, the image of your character changes for 5 seconds? in this case you should implement a listener and then open a timer to schedule a timer task

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask()  {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //reset your character to normal state
            }
        }
};
new Timer().schedule(task, 5000);
```

Comment: Use a `javax.swing.Timer`  for this.  It will endure that GUI updates are performed on the EDT.